# Error with Python + requests: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1006)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, urllib3

I have been struggling with a simple requests.get("https://www.boe.es/rss/canal_leg.php?l=l&c=118"). I am getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 635, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 774, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 459, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 503, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1006)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.boe.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rss/canal_leg.php?l=l&c=118 (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1006)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Propuestas\2022-Regulación\03-Codificación\Regulation\database\updater.py", line 545, in update_database
    req     = requests.get(source[1], headers={'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)})
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.boe.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rss/canal_leg.php?l=l&c=118 (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

I am currently using:

- requests 2.31.0
- urllib3 2.0.4  (tried with 2.0.2, 1.16.16 and 1.24.3)
- OpenSSL 3.0.9
- Python 3.11.15

I have triyed setting "verify=False" in requests and checked the server characteristics in SSLLabs, and they seem correct (I had never had an issue until recently): https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.boe.es

Also, as already mentioned, I tried with different versions of urllib3 and also requests (I do not remember which of this last one).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am having the same issue.